# ECLIPSE E4 dependencies issue

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rcp, e4

Basically I have imported an external plugin to my E4 application, now when I try to run it using the command in the product tab "Launch an eclipse application" it fails because of Missing Constraints.

Instead, if I go thru "Run Configuration" -> "Plugins" -> "Add Required Plugin" -> "RUN" It works like a charm.

I also tried to import, as dependencies of my `MANIFEST file`, the missing libraries but I always get the same problem.

Example of missing constraint:

```
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.telespazio.optsat.wizard.xygraph [961]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph; bundle-version="1.0.0.201506151822"
       org.eclipse.nebula.visualization.xygraph [994]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.draw2d
```

Comment: Have you put all the plugins in the Dependencies section of the .product file?  They need to be listed there.

Comment: Yes greg I have already done that :-(

Comment: greg let me rephrase my answer, basically my .product file is based on features. Therefore plugins are indirectly linked to it, I put plugins in a feature which is then imported into my .product file.

Comment: Actually I think 'Launch an eclipse application' just uses the 'Run > Run Configuration > Eclipse application' for your product.

Comment: then do you have any idea why it doesn't work? While manually executing the "Run Configuration" option does? Do I still miss some dependencies using  'Launch an eclipse application'?

Comment: If you have more than one Run Configuration I suppose it might choose the wrong one (although it usually asks which to run in this case).

Comment: mmm... otherwise thinking about the "feature" which acts as wrapper for the imported plugins, what should i check to be sure that it's not the culprit?

Comment: Guys I solved this problem... I was missing a library (org.eclipse.draw2d) which later on I added to the "feature" already imported into my .product file.